# Tracker.Current is not initialized in Sitecore

Tags: xdb, sitecore-client

I have created a Sitecore instance and Synced the code from TFS server using TDS. While accessing the Items from Sitecore Content Editor ,the following error occurs.

```
    [InvalidOperationException: Tracker.Current is not initialized]
   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args) +335
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists) +39
   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartAnalyticsPipeline.Run() +363
   Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcEvents.RequestBegin.StartTracking.Process(RequestBeginArgs args) +137
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +74
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +923
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

1.Mongodb is running

2.Xdb.tracking.enabled is true

Please help me out to solve the same. I am trying to setup Sitecore instance as local in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Copy Hostname from **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** in **Analytics.HostName** in Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Config as shown in screenshot. After that this should work fine.

[image]

Comment: Analytics.Hostname should really be empty.

Comment: I did the same , but the same issue persist

Comment: Did you follow this link?  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/analytics-tracker-current-is-not-initialized-error-after-changing-clustername