# Tracker.Current is not initialized error, despite Xdb.Enabled being turned off

Tags: xdb

We are seeing the error `Tracker.Current is not initialized` appearing in our logs, despite the fact that we have `Xdb.Enabled` set to false and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` set to true (we are using some basic personalization rules, but not storing anything to MongoDB). What other things should I check to eliminate this error message from the logs?

On a side note, our layout does not have `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` and I assume this is not needed as we are not using Xdb; is this the right assumption?

Comment: Is your Mongo DB up and running?

Comment: Do you have xDB in your Sitecore license?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: @PeterProchazka We're not using MongoDB (hence Xdb.Enabled being set to false), we do have xDB available in the license and we're using 8.2 u 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` in your layout. Without this, Sitecore will not identify the request as being a legitimate one and instead detect it as being a robot.

Since you have set `Xdb.Enabled = false` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled = true`, you are using [in-memory tracking of users](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/357/135) which will allow you to personalize based on session activity. The tracker needs to be initialized to allow you to do this, which means the visitor needs to be identified as not being a robot first.

You should also [read this answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/4433/135) which may help resolve issues with multi-server set up.