# Analytics.Tracker.Current is null in Sitecore 9 Update-1 Forms submit action with "Next" navigation step

Tags: tracking, sitecore-forms

I'm trying to implement custom submit action in Sitecore 9 Forms according to [the guide](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details), but found the problem with `Tracker.Current` which is `null` while accessing from `SubmitActionBase`.

`Tracker` is fine in other areas (e.g. while accessing from view controller). If I call `Tracker.StartTracking();` inside the action then `Tracker.Current` is ok as well.

Additional conditions:

- form is ajax enabled
- save action is called on "Next" navigation step, not on "Submit"

**Is this expected behaviour in Forms submit action?**

Here's part of the code:

```
public class UpdateContact : SubmitActionBase<UpdateContactData>
{
    public UpdateContact(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
    {
    }

    protected override bool Execute(UpdateContactData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
    {
        //Tracker.Enabled is true
        //Sitecore.Context.Site.Tracking().EnableTracking is true
        //Tracker.IsActive is false
        var contact = Tracker.Current.Contact; //Tracker.Current is null
    }
}
```

Comment: This also happens in my setup. Any news about the bug from Sitecore support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received feedback from Sitecore support:

> The mentioned behavior is expected because the tracker should be only triggered upon a submit as it is expensive to keep it alive after navigating to the next or previous page

So it looks that it's not a bug. Tracker is not initialized in Forms "Next" or "Previous" navigation step. To workaround it, you can either change the form to non-ajax, or initialize the tracker inside your action code:

```
if (Tracker.Current == null && Tracker.Enabled)
{
    Tracker.StartTracking();
}
...
//access Tracker.Current
```

I checked this method and visits history looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to identify contact and then you can use Tracker.Current.Contact notation. You need to use code from this article https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/digital%20marketing/sitecore%20forms/setting%20up%20and%20configuring/walkthrough%20creating%20a%20custom%20submit%20action%20that%20updates%20contact%20details and it's execute method. We had no issues implementing similar code in our solution recently.

Comment: Hi Peter, this is exactly what I try to use, it's linked in my question. The problem is with Execute method, where Tracker.Current is null (not Tracker.Current.Contact) so the method throws exception. It works fine for me if I add to the code: Tracker.StartTracking(), before calling Tracker.Current.Contact.

Comment: It is working for us without any problem. Do you have XDB tracking disabled or enabled? See here -> https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/experience_management/configuring/disabling_xdb_and_the_xdb_tracker

Comment: Take a look also into this thread -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/analytics-tracker-current-is-not-initialized-error-after-changing-clustername/4433#4433

Comment: Try also in your Execute method what are values for these parameters -> Tracker.IsActive and Sitecore.Context.Site.Tracking().EnabledTracking

Comment: xDB tracking is enabled. If called from controllers Tracker.Current is not null and also my visits appear in db and Experience Profile. 
The only problem is within submit action code; inside Execute method I have:
Tracker.Enabled = true, 
Sitecore.Context.Site.Tracking().EnableTracking = true, 
Tracker.IsActive = false, 
Tracker.Current = null

Comment: I found the conditions where the issue happens. It's only when form is ajax (which is default) and save action is set to "Next", not "Submit".

Comment: That sounds like a bug. I would love a Sitecore Support ticket

Comment: Already contacted support, I will update the answer after I receive their feedback. For now the workaround is to turn off ajax form, or to call Tracker.StartTracking() inside action code.

Comment: Keeping fingers crossed :)